# Weird Spring MVC context configuration behavior

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

For some reasons, I need to name the XML files for the Spring Context in a way different from the standard.

Yes, I know that this is a basic question and there are several responses to it on Stack Overflow, for example:

- [Spring Context Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519337/spring-context-configuration)
- [Spring MVC Context Hiearchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723728/spring-mvc-context-hiearchy)
- [Spring-MVC: What are a "context" and "namespace"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451325/spring-mvc-what-are-a-context-and-namespace)

However, my question is a little bit trickier than those, because the system only runs if the web.xml file has BOTH **<init-param>** and **<context-param>** doing THE SAME THING, as showed in the code below:

```
   <!--
   TAG A: <init-param>
    -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/myDearServlet.xml,
            /WEB-INF/springSecurityStuff.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
```

AND

```
   <!--
   TAG B: <context-param>
   -->
   <context-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
       <param-value>
           /WEB-INF/myDearServlet.xml,
           /WEB-INF/springSecurityStuff.xml
       </param-value>
   </context-param>
```

If I eliminate only the **TAG A: <init-param>** the system doesn't run and the error is:

> > java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [**/WEB-INF/my-dispatcher-servlet.xml**]
> >     
> > *(the name of the servlet is "my-dispatcher")*

and if I eliminate only the **TAG B: <context-param>** the system doesn't run either and the error is:

> > Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [**/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml**]

If I don't eliminate any of them the system runs normally. Here is the web.xml that works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <display-name>Weird Spring MVC</display-name>

    <!-- SPRING MVC SERVLET -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>my-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <!--
        TAG A: <init-param>
        -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/myDearServlet.xml,
                /WEB-INF/springSecurityStuff.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>my-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!--
    TAG B: <context-param>
    -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/myDearServlet.xml,
            /WEB-INF/springSecurityStuff.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Does anyone have a simple(?) explanation for this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Almir Campos.

Answer (score 3):

There are two things here:

- The root `ApplicationContext`, which is loaded by `ContextLoaderListener`, which by defaults looks for `applicationContext.xml` file to load the context.
- The `ServletContext` for each `DispatcherServlet` in your application, which is the child of the root context. The configuration file for each dispatcher servlet is by default in the pattern `<servletname>-servlet.xml`. Since the name of the servlet here is `my-dispatcher`, the `DispatcherServlet` needs a `my-dispatcher-servlet.xml` in classpath.

Now, if you don't have either of those files, and have different file names for either of those contexts, you have to configure them in the `web.xml`. That you do with `contextConfigLocation` parameter inside the `<context-param>` tag for *root* `ApplicationContext` and `<init-param>` tag for the `DispatcherServlet`.

So, if you remove any of them, default files for the respective context will be searched for, which you don't have, and hence you see those errors.

**See also:**

- [Difference between applicationContext.xml and spring-servlet.xml in Spring Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3652090/1679863)
- [Spring XML file configuration hierarchy help/explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7774295/1679863)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, Rohit. But, is there a way to avoid this redundant configuration?

Comment: @AlmirCampos Why the configuration seems redundant to you? If you really want to avoid, then use the default file for each context, and you don't need to give any of them then.

Comment: Because it's necessary repeat the code: "<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/myDearServlet.xml,
                /WEB-INF/springSecurityStuff.xml
            </param-value>". It's weird for me, because this is precisely we try to avoid all the time. How I said before, I need to use a different name.

Comment: @AlmirCampos You have to do it. Those are for 2 different configurations. However, you can avoid putting all the configuration files, by just having a single configuration file, and importing the others in that file. That way, you just have to put that file only in the `<param-value>` tag.

Comment: I think that have a configuration file is a very good suggestion. Thank you, Rohit.